# Как по Bluetooth достать СМС сообщения с телефона?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Есть возможность доставать список звонков, контактов, а смс сообщения возможно достать из сопряжённого устройства?
Как это сделать?

При условии что только на одном устройстве (где должно все отображаться) установлено наше ПО

Comment: Есть. Курить Bluetooth PBAP и Bluetooth MAP профили. Перед ними - курить OBEX.

Comment: Это будет работать если:
При условии что только на одном устройстве(где должно все отображаться) установлена наше ПО

Comment: Это будет работать в любом случае, если целевое устройство поддерживает указанные выше профили. Все современные смартфоны поддерживают MAP  и PBAP. Ну и для звонков еще HFP нужен (хотя бы Control Channel).

Comment: Спасибо ребята!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно, если аппарат поддерживает bluetooth профиль [Message Access Profile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Bluetooth_profiles#Message_Access_Profile_(MAP))

Пример реализации клиента [здесь](https://github.com/androidriver/packages_apps_Bluetooth)

**Предупреждение:** поскольку в API Android MAP профиль не входит, то требуется низкоуровневая реализация [протокола MAP](https://www.bluetooth.org/DocMan/handlers/DownloadDoc.ashx?doc_id=215400), что и сделано в указанном примере.

P.S. Обычно автомобильные блютус киты все более-менее поддерживают чтение и отправку SMS - именно для них и был разработан профиль MAP

Answer (score 2):

Существует и "родная" реализация MAP клиента, но в смартфонах она в прошивку не включается. Например тут [MAP клиент в Oreo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/opt/bluetooth/+/oreo-release/src/android/bluetooth/client/map?autodive=0/).